# How to compare between values of different files in python

Tags: python, file, networking

I'm very new at Python and very inexperienced working with files. That's why, I'm facing a huge problem making a simple program. There are two files input in my program:

**file1.txt:**

```
access-list 1 deny 172.16.4.13 0.0.0.0
access-list 1 permit 172.16.5.0 0.0.0.255

interface EO
ip access-group 1 out
```

**file2.txt:**

```
172.16.4.13 172.16.3.2
172.16.5.2 172.16.3.4
172.16.5.0 172.16.3.4
```

The output will something like this:

```
172.16.4.13 172.16.3.2 denied
172.16.5.0 172.16.3.4 permit
```

My logic is:

1. Saving the **deny/permit** word from **file1.txt** at **permission** variable
2. Saving the fisrt *ip* address from **file1.txt** at **ip** variable
3. Saving the two *ip* address from **file2.txt** at **source** and **destination** variable respectively
4. Comparing the **ip** variable with **source** variable and if they are equal, print the line as `ip/source, destination permit/deny`

For this, I've arranged my code the following way:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt","r")

line = file1.readline()
while line:
    values = line.split()
    permission = values[2]
    ip = values[3]
    line = file1.readline()



file2 = open("file2.txt","r")

line = file2.readline()
while line:
    value = line.split()
    source = value[0]
    destination = value[1]
    if source == ip:
        print(ip, permission, destination)  
    line = file2.readline()

file2.close()

file1.close()
```

But, this is not working properly :( How can I write this simple program?

Comment: your indenting is wrong for one thing, but this method won't really get you what you want you are ignoring the mask part of the thing - in your example access-list 1 permit 172.16.5.0 0.0.0.255 would also allow 172.16.5.2 172.16.3.4 - which you ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    fd1 = {}
    for ln in f1:
        if ln.startswith('access-list'):
            vals = ln.split()
            fd1[vals[3]] = vals[2]

with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    for ln in f2:
        vals = ln.split()
        if vals[0] in fd1:
            print vals[0], fd1[vals[0]], vals[1]
```

part of your original problem was that you were not storing the info from file1 - you only looked at the last item
remember this will only work for exact matches not ranges as i mentioned in comment above

Comment: This is giving me an error at this line: vals = ln.split(): !

Comment: oops i had a : at the end

Comment: One question: What did you meant with word "fd1"?

Comment: its just a dictionary to store the first file in so iguess FileDictionary1